# Identity on Fibonacci numbers: $F_{2n}^2=F_{2n+2}F_{2n-2}+1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci Sequence ($F_1=F_2=1, F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$).
Prove that $F_{2n}^2=F_{2n+2}F_{2n-2}+1$.

I've tried everything from induction to telescoping series but I haven't got close. They seem to make the identity even more messy. The main problem is with the squared term and the 1 at the end.
Does Pell's Equation or continued fractions have anything to do with this?

Comment: A good idea might be trying to derive a recursive formula for $G_n=F_{2n}$ (not entirely sure if this will work, though)

Comment: This is a specific case of Catalan's/Cassini's identity ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Other_identities)).

Comment: You can prove it using the closed form expression, that way seems easiest to me.

Comment: Don't worry guys, I solved it using induction. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: [Induction proof on Fibonacci sequence: $F(n-1) \cdot F(n+1) - F(n)^2 = (-1)^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523925/induction-proof-on-fibonacci-sequence-fn-1-cdot-fn1-fn2-1n) and
[Fibonacci identity: $f_{n-1}f_{n+1} - f_{n}^2 = (-1)^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20948/fibonacci-identity-f-n-1f-n1-f-n2-1n?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: First prove the following: $\forall n \geq 1: F_{n+1}\cdot F_{n-1}-F_n^2=(-1)^n$, then use it to prove: $\forall n \geq 1: F_{n+2}\cdot F_{n-2}-F_n^2 = (-1)^{n+1}$, then replace $n$ with $2n$ to get the sought identity.

Answer (score 3):

We can try to derive the recurrence for the sequence $(F_{2n})$. (This was already suggested [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332354/identity-on-fibonacci-numbers-f-2n2-f-2n2f-2n-21/1335067#comment2707138_1332354).) Then we can get matrix form for it, similar as the well-known [matrix form for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784710/how-to-prove-fibonacci-sequence-with-matrices).

This is a very natural thing to do for anybody who saw derivation of [similar identity for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20948/fibonacci-identity-f-n-1f-n1-f-n2-1n) based on determinants.

So we first notice that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n=2F_n+F_{n-1}=3F_n-F_{n-2}$. So we have
$$F_{2n+2}=3F_{2n}-F_{2n-2}.$$

This gives us
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  F_{2n+2} & F_{2n} \\
  F_{2n} & F_{2n-2} 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  3 &-1 \\
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  F_{2n} & F_{2n-2} \\
  F_{2n-2} & F_{2n-4}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So by induction we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  F_{2n+2} & F_{2n} \\
  F_{2n} & F_{2n-2}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  3 &-1 \\
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^n
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 &-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If we take determinants on both sides, we get
$$F_{2n+2}F_{2n-2}-F_{2n}^2=-1,$$
which is equivalent to the identity in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The difference equation $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_{n}$ admits the solution
\begin{align}
F_{n} = \frac{\alpha^{n} - \beta^{n}}{\alpha - \beta}
\end{align}
where $2 \alpha = 1 + \sqrt{5}$ and $2 \beta = 1 - \sqrt{5}$. Now,
\begin{align}
F_{2n-2} F_{2n+2} &= \frac{1}{5} \left(\alpha^{2n-2} - \beta^{2n-2} \right) \left( \alpha^{2n+2} - \beta^{2n+2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \, \left( \alpha^{4n} - \alpha^{2n-2} \beta^{2n+2} - \alpha^{2n+2} \beta^{2n-2} + \beta^{4n} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \, \left( \alpha^{4n} - \alpha^{4} - \beta^{4} + \beta^{4n} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \left( L_{4n} - L_{4} \right) = \frac{L_{4n} - 7}{5} \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $L_{n}$ are the Lucas numbers and have the form $L_{n} = \alpha^{n} + \beta^{n}$. Consider the square of $F_{2n}$.
\begin{align}
F_{2n}^{2} &= \frac{1}{5} \, \left( \alpha^{4n} - 2 \alpha^{2n} \beta^{2n} + \beta^{4n} \right) = \frac{L_{4n} - 2}{5}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
By comparison of equations (1) and (2) it is evident that
\begin{align}\tag{3}
F_{2n}^{2} = F_{2n-2} F_{2n+2} + 1 
\end{align}
which is the desired result.

Comment: Would the downvoter(s) care to make comments?

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for
the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649). (Of course, there is no guarantee that somebody will respond.)