# Determine the matrix for every n,$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n$

Is the a formula which give us the matrix for every n? I should make a proof with induction.

Comment: What do you mean by "optional"?

Comment: I mean for every n

Comment: What is the problem? How we can find a value for $n$ without some condition?

Comment: I have to find the matrix for every n. It has to be a formula.

Comment: A better question: what *can't* it be?

Comment: How can I find the n-th matrix without n matrix multiplication?

Comment: Why don't you do like, 3 matrix multiplications, and see if a pattern pops up?

Comment: I see the pattern, but I can't make a proof for the whole matrix. I should probably make a mathematical induction

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers-beginpmatrix11-10-end
and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784710/how-to-prove-fibonacci-sequence-with-matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$

Where $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: Is this really a hint or a solution?

Comment: I see it as a hint more than a solution. My intention was to show the OP where to look for in order to start an inductive argument.