# Fibonacci and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fibonacci-numbers

Consider Matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Investigate the sequence of powers of $A$
(i.e. $A^n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4,\ldots$.

Verify that $$A^n = \begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} &F_n \\ F_n & F_{n−1}\end{pmatrix}$$ for $n \geq 20$, where $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

I don't get it, please help. Thank you!

Comment: How about trying to prove this statement by induction on $n$?

Comment: What don't you get? You don't get what a matrix is? you don't get what $A^n$ means? you don't get what a Fibonacci number is? Meet us halfway – someone will help you.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784710/how-to-prove-fibonacci-sequence-with-matrices

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$A^{n+1} = A\cdot A^n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_{n}\\ F_{n} & F_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$$$$$$
$$ = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} + F_n & F_{n} + F_{n-1}\\ F_{n} + F_{n-1} & F_{n} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+2} & F_{n+1}\\ F_{n+1} & F_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Induction reasoning for $n\ge2$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_{n}\\F_{n}&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+2}&F_{n+1}\\F_{n+1}&F_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^{2}=\begin{bmatrix}F_{2}&F_{1}\\F_{1}&F_{0}\end{bmatrix}$$