# If $A=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ then $A^n=~?$

Tags: matrices

> Let $A=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&1\\1&0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.
> Then $A^n~?$

I saw $A^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2&1\\1&1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Is there any similarity or any recurrence relation ?

Comment: Yes, eigenvalues of $A$ are ${1+\sqrt 5\over 2}$ and ${1-\sqrt 5\over 2}$

Comment: This should remind you of the fibonacci recurrence.  $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}f_2\\f_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}f_2+f_1\\f_2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: By approaching from the other direction of diagonalization of the matrix and taking the relation to the Fibonacci recurrence into account, one can then arrive at one of the elementary methods of proving the closed form to the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: DietrichBurde: I think your suggested link assumes OP must know the Fibonacci sequence, which only provides **one** approach to the question. But it does certainly not require any *a priori* knowledge in that sequence.

Comment: @mrsamy The duplicate answers the question of what $A^n$ is, and that is the above question (see title). So $F_n$ appears naturally.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I may misread something, but your link explicitly says "How to prove **Fibonacci sequence** with matrices".

Comment: @mrsamy Yes, you are right, that's what the link says. But the post itself (and the linked one) proves a formula for $A^n$, and this is what the OP wants. For $n=2$ he found it himself.

Comment: @DietrichBurde there may be a better duplicate post anyway. Without context, nobody knows what $F_n$ means. But I agree, yes, this certainly relates to the Fibonacci sequence and it worths knowing that. :-)

Comment: @mrsamy Yes, I agree that there may be other duplicates. But I find it good enough that an explicit formula is proved for $A^n$. That's the important point for me. And it leads in addition to Fibonacci numbers, and that's also good.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: There are various pedagogical approaches. Point taken :-)

Answer (score 1):

Find the eigenvalues of $A$ and write $A$ as $SJS^{-1}$ where $J$ is some nice matrix.

Then find $(SJS^{-1})^n$.

The point is that it is very easy to find a "recursive" relation in $J^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$A^n=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} F_{n+1}& F_n\\F_n & F_{n-1}\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ where $F_n=n-$th *fibonacci  number*.

Notice this is true for $n=1$. Now use Induction to prove my statement. You should read abot the matrix representation of **fibonacci number** [here]
(htttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: Yes, see the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784710/how-to-prove-fibonacci-sequence-with-matrices).